# Why switch to Azure Web app / API to Multi-tenanted is not working?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, multi-tenant

I have a `Web app / API` deployed on `Microsoft Azure` working in single tenant mode. I need to enable users from other tenants to be able to use my API.

I found this post with step-by-step guide to enable multi-tenant authentication, 
https://blog.mastykarz.nl/configuring-multi-tenant-authentication-azure-app-service-authentication-options/

but when I try to change Web API's `Multitenanted` property to Yes, it says "failed to update App ID URI application property" with following error detail:

```
{"errorCode":"HostNameNotOnVerifiedDomain","localizedErrorDetails":
{"errorDetail":"Host name in property identifierUris is not on any verified
 domain of the company or its subdomain."},
"operationResults":null,"timeStampUtc":"2017-01-11T00:14:37.3270764Z",
"clientRequestId":"...","internalTransactionId":"...",
"upn":"...@gmail.com","tenantId":"...","userObjectId":"..."}
```

Currently App ID URI holds address of my Web API (and it is working in single tenant mode as expected) `https://(..).azurewebsites.net` is this not correct for multi tenanted mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. With multi-tenant apps the App ID URI has to be in a domain in your AAD. So if my AAD contains domains like test.onmicrosoft.com and company.com, then allowed URIs would be:

- https://test.onmicrosoft.com/MyApi
- https://company.com/MyApi

You don't own the azurewebsites.net domain and thus can't use it.

Comment: Hi! I did buy custom domain name through Azure management portal (it's godaddy.com behind the scenes), but I can't find an information on how to Verify this domain. I created a `DNS zone` from management portal, added TXT record data, that I see when I open properties for this custom domain. But for no effect. Then I tried to go to godaddy.com, but their support redirected me back to Azure... Do you know how to register custom domain if it is purchased through Azure portal?

Comment: Have you tried this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-domains-add-azure-portal ?

Comment: Thanks for information! I managed to add those DNS records going through `App service` -> `Custom domain`, then clicking on Domain name - it took me to `Manage domain` page, from there clicking on `Advanced management` lead to site https://dcc.secureserver.net/manage/ where I could add DNS records. After that my Custom domain was accepted as Verified.

Comment: But when you are creating AAD Apps from Azure Portal, its allowing to enable multi-tenant irrespective of the URI in a domain or not.

But when creating AAd apps and service pricipals from powershell it not working.

Comment: This may have changed slightly in the last 2 years ;)

Answer (score 2):

From the helper text for App ID URI in the management portal:

> The URI is used as a unique logical identifier for your app. The URI **must be in a verified custom domain for an external user to grant your app access to their data in Microsoft Azure AD**

That being said, since the App ID URI doesn't have any functional implications, you should still be able to do your testing by setting your App ID URI to something along the lines of:

```
http://<localhost_or_whatever>.<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com
```

But keeping your Reply URLs as they are pointing to your .azurewebsite.net URIs.

This should let you proceed with configuring your app as multi-tenant and do your testing with whatever site you want.

*Note: I'm reusing my answer from very similar question: From my response to similar question: 
[Azure AD Error after editing manifest to enable availableToOtherTenants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729477/azure-ad-error-after-editing-manifest-to-enable-availabletoothertenants/)*