# Cannot set AppID URI: "Property identifierUris is invalid"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I've created an application in my AAD and I want to use it to authenticate my web API. In order to do that, I need to set the application ID URI, which is going to be used for defining scopes.

Whatever app ID URI entered gets rejected with message `Property identifierUris is invalid. [V1Z2e]`.

I've tried to set the URI in Azure Portal both in UI and in manifest with the same result. Also I've tried various values:

- `api://<clientId>` as offered by the Portal itself, and by [this ASP.NET Core Web Api authentication sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API).
- `https://<tenant_name>/<application_name>` as suggested by [Azure troubleshooting page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/registration-config-specific-application-property-how-to?WT.mc_id=UI_AAD_Registered_Apps_Troubleshooting_L2_Overview).
- `http://<localhost_or_whatever>.<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com` as suggested by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37741034/988950).

Is it a bug in Azure Portal? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I was able to add `https://dctest.azurewebsites.net` and `api://dctest` to my app there now without issue. Not much help to you i'm afraid.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you trying to add the URI on the API app registration (not the client app registration)?

Comment: There was another question now with this same problem. So could be a bug in the API/portal. I didn't have this issue in my tenant :\

Comment: Have you tried to create an new application?

Comment: I've tried to create a new app and apply the required settings one by one. It turns out, that the problem is with public client setting (the one to allow ROPC etc.). AppID URI cannot be set, when public client is allowed. I will try to create two apps -- one for ROPC login and one for API.

Comment: @juunas, not sure what do you mean by API/client app? I thought there could be just one app both for user login and API.

Comment: You can have more than 1 :) An app can require permissions to another app which represents an API. You can also use one registration for both the client and API. I prefer using different registrations.

Comment: @juunas, yes, having two registered apps helped. Would you like to write an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, it seems that registering two apps in Azure AD helped. One app for the API where you define the app ID URI and scopes.
And another app for the client app, which then requires those scopes on the API.